# Trivializations of gerbes as generalisation of trivializations of line bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gerbes

I understood  gerbes as generalization of line bundle [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298437/confusion-in-definition-of-gerbes-in-hitchins-notes)

In this, I am trying to understand how to generalize notion of trivialization of line bundle to the notion of trivialization of gerbes. I am following [this notes of Hitchin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9907034.pdf) for this.

It says that

> We can’t point to a gerbe as a space in the same way that we can for a line bundle, but there is a fundamental notion which helps to understand them – a
> trivialization of a gerbe.

Further, it says,

> Recall that for line bundles, trivialization is a non-vanishing section $s$ of $L$. A unitary trivialization $s/||s||$ is also a section of the principal $S^1$ bundle. In terms of transition functions, this is a collection of functions $f_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow S^1$ such that on $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ we have $f_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta}f_\beta$.
>
> Given another trivialization $f_\alpha':U_\alpha\rightarrow S^1$ we have $f_\alpha'=g_{\alpha\beta}f_\beta'$ and so we see that $$\frac{f_\alpha'}{f_\alpha}=\frac{f_\beta'}{f_\beta}.$$
> Thus, $f_\alpha'/f_\alpha$ is restriction of a global function to $U_\alpha$ and we see that the difference of two local trivializations of a line bundle is the global function $X\rightarrow S^1$.

Here, $L$ is a unitary line bundle or its principal $S^1$ bundle of unitary frames. I do not know what is a unitary bundle. I assume that $L$ is just a  line bundle $\pi:L\rightarrow X$.

I understand that for line bundles, trivialization is same as giving a non vanishing section of line bundle.

He generalises notion of trivialization to that of gerbes.

In case of line bundles, this is collection of maps $f_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow S^1$.

In case of gerbes it has to be on $1$ fold intersection extra i.e.,
$f_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\rightarrow S^1$.

The condition $f_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta}f_\beta$ in case of line bundles should have its similar generalization in case of gerbes. I fail to understand how this generalisation is the condition $$g_{\alpha\beta\gamma}=f_{\alpha\beta}f_{\beta\gamma}f_{\gamma\alpha}$$

Any suggestion on understanding this better is useful.

Comment: If you’re not already familiar with it, you should look up the description of the first chern class in terms of Cech cohomology.

Comment: @AaronBergman Can you suggest me some place to see that and tell me how does it help to understand this better.

Comment: Try Section 1.1 of Griffiths and Harris

Comment: @AaronBergman That is useful, thanks a lot. I was thinking Principal bundle comes with a local trivialization... I was thinking Giving another trivialization is like giving another principal bundle structure on same tuple $(\pi:P\rightarrow M)$ just like giving another smooth structure on a manifold... Isnt't it the situation?

Comment: A principal bundle does not come with a local trivialization -- that's extra structure. I'd say it's like a different atlas of charts on a manifold, not like a different smooth structure. What you'll find is that changing the local trivialization doesn't change the Cech cohomology class.

Comment: @AaronBergman i Understand now to some extent.. thanks, I will write down an answer here on e I understand it correctly

Comment: @AaronBergman I am little confused. For what concept do we use the term local trivialization? One condition in definition of principal bundle in Kobayashi is "given $x\in M$ there exists a diffeo $\psi:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times G$ with $\psi(u)=(\pi(u),\varphi(u))$ where $\varphi:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow G$ is such that $\varphi(ug)=\varphi(u)g$ for all $g\in G$ and $u\in \pi^{-1}(U)$"... We can make a choice of this $\psi$.. do we call $\{(U_i,\psi_i)\}$ a local trivialization on cover $\{U_i\}$ of $M$??

Comment: @AaronBergman  If we choose another $\psi$  say $\{(U_i,\psi')\}$ on same $U_i$ do we call it a different local trivialization??  What does it mean to say "for line bunldes a trivialization is a non-vanishing section $s$ of $L$"?? Trivialization is a choice of map $L\rightarrow M\times G$, right? Given a choice of map $\psi:L\rightarrow M\times G$, we get a section $s:M\rightarrow L$ given by $m\mapsto \psi^{-1}(m,e)$.. Similarly, given a section $s:M\rightarrow L$, we have an isomorphsim $M\times G\rightarrow L$ given by $(m,g)\mapsto s(m)g$ which gives a trivialization.

Comment: @AaronBergman can you please take some time and respond for my doubt. I think I misunderstood the concept.. is there any way I can contact you personally?